# Polymorphism: accessing static members via class literal or object

Tags: c++, static, polymorphism

Suppose you need to access a member of a struct/class either via the class literal, or through an inherited object of that class. It might looks something like this:

```
struct Component {
    static const long key = 0;
    virtual long getKey() {return key;};
};

struct FooComponent : Component {
    static const long key = 0x1;
    virtual long getKey() {return key;};
};

struct BarComponent : Component {
    static const long key = 0x2;
    virtual long getKey() {return key;};
};
```

With the above, `key` can be accessed either via:

```
long key = FooComponent::key;
```

or

```
FooComponent foo;
long key = foo.getKey();
```

Now my question is: is there some cleaner, less redundant way of achieving the above? Ideally `virtual long getKey() {return key;};` would only need to be specified once, not for every inherited class.

EDIT:

Class hierarchy *is* important. The components are stored in a single container, in my case an unordered_map:

```
std::unordered_map<long, std::unique_ptr<Component>> components;
```

Comment: `template <long key> struct Component{ long getKey() { return key; } }; struct FooComponent : Component<0x1> {};`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry I wrote my answer then I saw your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending @iavr's answer to the new requirements:

```
struct Component {
  virtual ~Component() {}
  virtual long getKey() { return 0; }
};

template <int Key>
struct KeyedComponent : Component {
  long getKey() { return Key; };
};

struct FooComponent : KeyedComponent<1> { };
struct BarComponent : KeyedComponent<2> { };
```

Tested with:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> components;
components.emplace_back(new FooComponent());
components.emplace_back(new BarComponent());

for (auto& component : components) {
  std::cout << component->getKey() << std::endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Implemented it, works like a charm. This is a really neat way of going about it! Thanks, great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Static polymorphism is your friend here:

```
template <long K = 0>
struct Component {
    static constexpr long key = K;
    long getKey() {return key;};
};

struct FooComponent : Component <0x1> {};

struct BarComponent : Component <0x2> {};
```

Comment: well, this is not the same thing. the original had a single class hierarchy. not sure whether this was a requirement, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks, Karoly, this is a requirement that I didn't think to specify. I've edited the question.